# How to block specific devices from wireless network?

Tags: router, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, blocking

I have a router(DLink) that broadcasts at both 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz. I wish to set up a filter such that all devices other than phones and tablets should connect to it. How can I do this? I'm not sure about MAC address filtering as I can change MAC addresses on most of my devices.

**UPDATE**

I did a little research on this, for those who might want to pick up from here.

It is hard to determine the type of device running in a network, primarily because the device might not want to give up details that could potentially compromise its security. One way is to run a script on the router to detect the type of OS running on the host.

Tools like `nmap` come in handy. It can create a fingerprint of the device and match against in its database. This needs at least one open port to detect the OS successfully. 99% of desktops/PCs that I tested on gave the right answer. Mobile devices made an abominably poor performance, `nmap` couldn't detect even a single device. This of course, could be because most devices have all the 1000 scanned ports closed. This is definitely harder to spoof and certainly better than MAC based filtering.

Remote OS detection is detailed [here](https://nmap.org/book/osdetect.html).

Comment: If someone can change their MAC address, do you think they couldn't change the "phone/tablet/PC" indication, if there was one?

Comment: @grawity I'm hoping they can't.

Comment: Also, I was trying `nmap` command, `nmap -O deviceip`. Perhaps someone can think of something on those lines?

Comment: That's the problem, though – 1) there _isn't_ any such indication, and 2) even if there was, someone would just find ways to change it, because that's... really not something that can possibly be useful for security purposes.

Comment: @grawity Maybe I don't want it to be that foolproof though. Looking for something just as secure as MAC filtering. Are you saying such device type filtering is impossible?

Comment: Yes, I'm saying it is impossible.

Comment: MAC filtering is not secure, Djack, because you can change a device's MAC address

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make a configuration to comply with such a rule.

But you can open the router web interface and go to Advanced tab along the top and then on Network Filter.

Put **MAC Filtering ON** and **ALLOW** listed computers to access the network. the rest will be implicitly denied.

Comment: How am I supposed to know which PCs will connect to it in the future?

Comment: @Djack You'll know because if they want to attach they'll have to ask you to add them to the whitelist.  At which point you can turn of the filtering, let them connect, add their MAC to the whitelist, and turn it back on.

Comment: Yes, and some firmware versions make it easier and show the connection attempts too, so you will be able to add them directly.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 No. The point of this is to automate the exercise.

Comment: You cannot on the given router. It (on default firmware) does not support MAC groups (the only thing you can use to identify). Only with a custom written ACL you can filter devices by manufacturer/type so you could distinguish between device types. So unless you are able to rewrite the router firmware, you can't do what you want.

Comment: @Overmind I don't think that's going to be a problem. There are custom firmwares, like `OpenWrt` and `DD-Wrt` supported on many D-Link routers.

Comment: Wildcards seems are not supported even in DDWRT. This got no answer yet. https://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=53303&sid=76202c29e7b3b7bcbd1205e7fa2ccc59